# A question on a double sum involving tenth roots of unity

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation

Let $\{z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_9\}$ be the set of the tenth roots of unity, excluding $1$. We have to find

$$\sum_{r=0}^{37}\sum_{i=1}^{9}z_i ^r$$

I know the sum of all roots equals $-1$ and the product of all roots is $-1$, but so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$ \sum_{r=0}^{37}z_i^r = \frac{z_i^{38}-1}{z_i-1}=\frac{z_i^{-2}-1}{z_i-1}=\frac{1}{z_i^2}\cdot\frac{1-z_i^2}{z_i-1}=-z_i^{-1}-z_i^{-2} $$
it is enough to exploit
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{9}z_i^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{9}z_i = -1 $$
and
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{9}z_i^{-2} = \sum_{i=1}^{9}z_i^2 = -1 $$
to get that the answer is simply $\color{red}{\large 2}$.

Comment: How you have written $\Sigma ^9_{i=1}z_i ^2=-1$

Comment: @user123733: that is the sum of a geometric sequence!

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^{9}\exp\frac{4\pi i k}{10} = 1+2\sum_{k=1}^{4}\exp\frac{2\pi i k}{5} = 1+2(-1) = -1.$$

Comment: In the above comment how you have written  $  1+2\sum_{k=1}^{4}\exp\frac{2\pi i k}{5}$